# quoting problem when use perl -e command in shell

Tags: linux, shell, perl, single-quotes

### With double quotes

The following command

```bash
$ cat ./multi_meta | jq .Partitions[].DocCount | perl -lne "$x += $_; END{ print $x;}"
```

gives me a syntax error：

```bash
syntax error at -e line 1, near "+="
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

### With single quotes

I get the correct result with

```bash
$ cat ./multi_meta | jq .Partitions[].DocCount | perl -lne '$x += $_; END{ print $x;}'
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Because with double quotes, the whole string is passed through your shell's variable expansion mechanisms before the Perl compiler sees the code. And as you don't have shell variables called `$x` or `$_`, the Perl compiler sees this:

```
+= ; END{ print ;}
```

With single quotes, your Perl variables are protected from expansion until the Perl compiler can see them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your shell expanding $x as it was a shell variable and not as a perl variable, the solution should be escape $ like this \$.

Comment: yes, need to escape all of the variables.